# User search pricing calculation

Tags: solr, price

I'm building a search engine which provide me a list of cap drivers. We have some requirements:

- User is searching cheapest cap driver to bring him from place a to place b. He can go from any place to any place.
- Default formula would be distance * price per mile
- But there are also special prices like AMSTERDAM to THE HAGUE would be always 100 EUR
- The price for each mile is season based winter/summers have different prices.
- Faceting search based on attributes. Like is there Champagne/Luxory/Male/Female driver/Etc etc.
- User want's to sort on cheapest ride/but also distance.

What would be the best approach to fit all there requirements? I've tried Solr but have not found a good solution for putting the price modal in there. Any ideas?

Comment: I had linked documentation for Solr FunctionQuery and Elasticsearch function_score queries to your Algolia post.  If you tried this with Solr, can you please revise this post with details about where you're getting stuck on the pricing model?

Comment: Strategy-wise, I feel like you'll need to handle the overrides: AMSTERDAM, THE HAGUE, in your client logic... But you might be able to index seasonal price-per-mile in separate fields (e.g. summer_ppd and winter_ppd) and have your client choose the appropriate field to sort/score at query time.